# Scrapy: how to crawl the URL I got from spider? exceptions.NameError: global name 'parse_detail' is not defined

Tags: python, scrapy, yield, nameerror

I practice scrapy and have a question:
I want to crawl the link I got from spider again and don't know how to do

Here is My code:
as you can see,the link I crawl will save in the parameter:movie_descriptionTW_URL
And I wrote `yield Request(movie_descriptionTW, parse_detail)` to send the result to def :

```
def parse_detail(self, response):
    print(response.url)
```

But there is an error : exceptions.NameError: global name 'parse_detail' is not defined
How to solve this?
Please teach me! Thank you

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from yahoo.items import YahooItem
from scrapy.http.request import Request   

class MySpider(Spider):   
    name = "yahoogo"
    start_urls = ["https://tw.movies.yahoo.com/chart.html"]  

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath("//tr")
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = YahooItem()
            ranking_list = site.xpath("td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()
            movie_descriptionTW  = site.xpath("(td[@class='c3']/*//a)[position() < last()-1]/text() | td[@class='c3']/a[1]/text() ").extract()
            movie_descriptionTW_URL = site.xpath("(td[@class='c3']/*//a[2]/@href) | td[@class='c3']/a[1]/@href ").extract()   

            # crawl again!
            yield Request(movie_descriptionTW, parse_detail)

            if ranking_list:    
                items.append(item)
        yield items     

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Comment: `parse_detail` is in this case a class method, so you'd need to use `self.parse_detail`.

Answer (score 0):

use `self.parse_detail` to refer to class methods like the following:

```
for url in movie_descriptionTW_URL:
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)
```

Comment: It works! but it has error said the type of url is list. can you teach me how to translate to string?

Comment: is `movie_descriptionTW_URL` a list? if so, yield a new Request for every url in it.

Comment: When you extract an xpath, it returns a list of matches, even if there's only one match. If you are sure that there will always be one and only one match, you can do `movie_descriptionTW_URL = site.xpath("(td[@class='c3']/*//a[2]/@href) | td[@class='c3']/a[1]/@href ").extract()[0]`